# Using Mongoose with IntelliJ IDEA Causes Unresolved Function or Method

Tags: node.js, mongodb, intellij-idea, mongoose

I just downloaded the 30-day trial of IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate Edition and I'm having an issue with the Node.js project I imported.

I am using Mongoose and am using the `find` and `findById` methods of my model classes fairly often. Since these methods are provided by mongoose and not actually defined explicitly in my model classes, IntelliJ does not seem to like them. Everywhere that I use the methods, I get an error saying "Unresolved function or method *xxx*".

I have read several other users stating they had similar issues with Node and WebStorm, but those all seemed to be with the code Node library and all of the answers said to use the `Node.js Globals` library. I have imported this library and tried downloading both `mongodb-DefinitelyTyped` and `mongoose-DefinitelyTyped` from the Libraries screen, and still cannot get the warnings to go away.

Comment: I'm having the same issue using WebStorm 10.0.4. Do you know of anything I can do to fix this?

Comment: As I mentioned in the comment below, it is unfortunately not properly supported in WebStorm right now until version 15. If you do not want to purchase the 15 upgrade, a way to make it work (it might be different in version 10) is to navigate to Settings>Editor>Inspections. In the main panel of Inspections, navigate to JavaScript>General and uncheck both "Unresolved JavaScript function" and "Unresolved JavaScript variable." This will stop you from getting any error messages for unresolved variables/functions, but that will also mean you won't get unexpected errors for Mongoose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided it was probably faster to contact JetBrains support since I didn't seem to be getting any quick solutions here. I guess this issue is a bug with IntelliJ IDEA 14 because they had me try the IntelliJ IDEA 15 EAP and it worked fine.

So I guess the solution is to go EAP or just wait for 15 if anybody else has this issue.